# Testing if a docopt command-line option is set in nim

Tags: command-line-arguments, nim-lang

I'm trying to write a nim program that can read either from the standard input or from a file given as a command-line option. I use docopt to parse the command line.

```nimrod
import docopt

const doc = """
This program takes input from a file or from stdin.

Usage:
  testinput [-i <filename> | --input <filename>]

-h --help              Show this help message and exit.
-i --input <filename>  File to use as input.
"""

when isMainModule:
  let args = docopt(doc)
  var inFilename: string
  for opt, val in args.pairs():
    case opt
    of "-i", "--input":
      inFilename = $args[opt]
    else:
      echo "Unknown option" & opt
      quit(QuitFailure)
  let inputSource =
    if inFilename.isNil:
      stdin
    else:
      echo "We have inFilename: " & inFilename
      open(inFilename)
```

The program compiles.

It doesn't crash when I give it a file on the command line:

```
$ ./testinput -i testinput.nim
We have inFilename: testinput.nim
```

But I get an IOError if I try to feed it from its stdin:

```
$ ./testinput < testinput.nim
We have inFilename: nil
testinput.nim(28)        testinput
system.nim(2833)         sysFatal
Error: unhandled exception: cannot open: nil [IOError]
```

How come `inFilename.isNil` is false, and yet the execution of the `else` branch tells me that `inFilename` "is" `nil`?

**Is there a correct and elegant way to do this, using docopt?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with docopt, but it seems to create an entry for each option in the doc, not for the options specified by user so your code's been getting `args == {"--input": nil}` and stringifying the `nil`.

The following will work correctly:

```
import docopt

const doc = """
This program takes input from a file or from stdin.

Usage:
  testinput [-i <filename> | --input <filename>]

-h --help              Show this help message and exit.
-i --input <filename>  File to use as input.
"""

when isMainModule:
  let args = docopt(doc)
  var inFilename: string
  if args["--input"]:
    inFilename = $args["--input"]
  if not inFilename.isNil:
    echo "We have inFilename: " & inFilename
  let inputSource =
    if inFilename.isNil:
      stdin
    else:
      open(inFilename)
```

Also note that you don't have to check for `"-i"` option as docopt knows it's an alias to `"--input"`.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer got me to have one more look at the documentation of docopt, and I found another way to do it. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of transforming the value of the option into a string with `$`, one can keep it as a `Value`, which is the type returned by `docopt`.

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/docopt/docopt.nim):

> `vkNone` (No Value)
>
> This kind of Value appears when there is an option which hasn't been set and has no default. It is false when converted `toBool`

One can apparently use the value of the option in a boolean expression, and it seems to be automatically interpreted as a `bool`:

```nimrod
import docopt

const doc = """
This program takes input from a file or from stdin.

Usage:
  testinput [-i <filename> | --input <filename>]

-h --help              Show this help message and exit.
-i --input <filename>  File to use as input.
"""

when isMainModule:
  let args = docopt(doc)
  var inFilename: Value
  for opt, val in args.pairs():
    case opt
    of "-i", "--input":
      inFilename = val
    else:
      echo "Unknown option" & opt
      quit(QuitFailure)
  let inputSource =
    if not bool(inFilename):
      stdin
    else:
      echo "We have inFilename: " & $inFilename
      open($inFilename)
```

Another usage of this behaviour is given in [this other anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48304193/1878788), and avoids setting the variable, therefore keeping it `nil`.